# Send multiple using Nexmo

Tags: python, vonage

How to send multiple numbers using nexmo with python

```
import nexmo


client = nexmo.Client(key='exxxxx', secret='Qxxxxxx')
client.send_message({
    'from': 'Nexmo',
    'to': '639354758282',
    'text': 'Hello from Nexmo',
})
```

Comment: If those are your real credentials you probably want to deactivate them as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Does this loop help to send SMS for multiple numbers? Or, you are looking for something else?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import nexmo

client = nexmo.Client(key='*******', secret='*********')
phones = ['Number 1', 'Number 2', 'Number 2']

for phone in phones:
 msg = 'Hello ' + phone + ' from Nexmo'
 response = client.send_message({
    'from': 'Nexmo',
    'to': phone,
    'text': msg,
 })
 print(response)
```

Comment: i am looking for how to send multiples numbers

Comment: Please explain. You want to send SMS to multiple numbers? If so, above script I have provided will do. Just replace "Number 1," "Number 2," and "Number 3" etc. in the phones Python list with the numbers you want to send.
If, however, your requirement is something different, please explain in detail. Thanks!